# Sql Agent job does not execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs, agent

I have create a sql agent job as follows

```
USE [Database]
GO
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[StoredProc_RPT_Test]
@batch_id = Null,
@StartDate = Null,
@EndDate = Null
SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

The Stored Procedure StoredProc_RPT_Test calls another stored procedure when all parameters are null. Which inserts data into a permanent table.

I can run StoredProc_RPT_Test manually and it works fine. The data is present in permanent table. However when i run the sql agent job no results in the permanent table?

Really puzzled. Is this because iam calling two stored procedures?

Comment: Seems like job failed. If job fails it will definitely writes a log with error number. Can you please provide me error number?

Comment: Job executed successfully. I tried running the job manually and it executes fine.  I tried to write some diagnostic statements into a dummy table and noticed that all statements are present before the stored procedure executes a assembly.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Please check and publish the SQL server Agent error. You could see how does it check in the article: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1916/best-practice-recycling-sql-server-agent-error-logs/#:~:text=In%20the%20Log%20File%20Viewer,and%20select%20View%20Agent%20Log.

Answer (score 2):

Did you checked the Job log for any failure message? Also please make sure the SQL server service account have execute permission on the procedures.

Comment: Job has been executed successfully. When I manually run the job executes but no results in the permanent table.  However if i run the stored procedure manually it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was SQL Server Agent has a default textsize of 1024. In my SQL Server Agent step before executing the stored procedure, I simply added the textize.

e.g.

```
SET TEXTSIZE 15000
EXEC dbo.yourspname @param1, @param2...
```

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably SQL Server Agent doesn't have enough permissions to run your SP. Set job owner (in a dialog) to the account which has permission.
When you run the job manually you do it in your context.

Answer (score 0):

Try to not select returned value just print inside of procedure.